# Override a CSS or JS file from the parent theme

Tags: javascript

Adding in the child theme a CSS file with the same name as the parent theme CSS file overrides the parent file. It doesn't seem to work JavaScript files.

How can I override a JavaScript file loaded from the parent theme?

Comment: Have you tried to replace it using hook_js_alter https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/8.2.x

Comment: cannot find the js from parent theme when printing $javascript ? (using the D7 hook)

Comment: Did you try examples from https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7.x, are you using advagg module or other module for js aggregation ?.

Comment: Generally you don't want to replace a JS file completely because it's very unlikely that you will want to change everything it does. Can you explain why you want to get rid of this one?

Comment: and if the js file contain behavior, you should override the behavior with the same name in your child theme .

Comment: it worked. @berramou if u like to write an answer i will accept it. We are using a theme parent for many sites of a platform but this js file is not appropriate to that specific site

Comment: Ok i will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`hook_js_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7.x) to replace your JS file (from parent theme) with the one in your child theme.

```
function child_theme_name_doc_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  $javascript['themes/parent_theme_name/js/parent_theme_name_navigation.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'child_theme_name') . '/js/child_theme_name_navigation.js';
}
```

Comment: and what is the way on D8?

Comment: for D8 hook_js_alter supported too https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/8.9.x

Answer (score 0):

in the theme.info

```
libraries-override:
  parent_theme_name/library_name:
    css:
      base:
        ; deactivate a file
        css/parent_theme_name_language_switcher.css: false
    js:
      ; override a file
      js/parent_theme_name_navigation.js: js/child_theme_name_navigation.js
```